# What's faster: to reorder a list of lists or to reorder a list of indexes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is faster: to reorder a list of lists or to reorder a list of integers?

Should I first represent the main list as list of indexes (to represent it as a list of ordinal type) of inner lists or I can work directly with list of lists?

Comment: How to you want to order them? If performance is critical, have you tried comparative testing?

Comment: give it a whirl and tell us

Comment: can you add an example of your two options?

Comment: Both have the same big-O complexity, so try both and measure them.

Answer (score 4):

From this test, you can see that they take about the same amount of time:

```
a = range(100)
b = [range(10) for _ in range(100)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import repeat
    n = 500
    r = 5

    print min(repeat('shuffle(a)', setup='from random import shuffle;from __main__ import a', repeat=r, number=n))
    print min(repeat('shuffle(b)', setup='from random import shuffle;from __main__ import b', repeat=r, number=n))
```

I noticed a *slight* speed advantage for reordering the list of ints, but it's neither significant, nor consistent enough to warrant using a list of indices. Sometimes, reordering the lists of lists is faster and vice versa.

This is because objects are binded to by reference values that get stored and passed around as variables, and *everything* is an object in Python, even `int` types. So "reordering lists within a list" is equivalent to "reordering numbers within a list" because all you're *really* doing is reordering a list of references to lists/numbers respectively.

You can think of a reference value as sort of like an address in memory that points to where the object is actually located. In Python terms, it's the `id` of the object. It's somewhat analogous to a pointer value in C/C++. In CPython, the `id` of an object is actually just it's address in memory, but this is an implementation detail, so don't count on it being the same across Python implementations.